# Media file format converter API for Android

Tags: java, android, converters, codec

I am looking for an API which can convert media file to any other format eg:- .3gp to .avi in java. 
I googled around and came accross ffmpeg but still no clue if it can be used to achieve functionality with android project.

If you can share some more information about any API that you have used then it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

It's available in the newer API.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

PS: If you get this working, let me know, I have a project where I intend to use this.

Comment: do you have any samples created using this ?

Comment: It's on my list of things to do once I figure out how to limit the frames.